# Forecasting dataset China Population period must be >= 2

Tags: python, time-series, fft, statsmodels

I'm attempting to use the Deterministic Process to forecast based on my dataset, which contains information like:

```
Date    Population  Increase in Population  Population Density  Increase in Population Density
1950-01-01  543979233   0.00    56.66   0.00
1951-01-01  553613988   1.77    57.67   1.77
1952-01-01  564954522   02.05   58.85   02.05
```

However, when I execute my Python code using DeterministicProcess, it raises an error:

```
dp = DeterministicProcess(
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
raise ValueError("period must be >= 2")
ValueError: period must be >= 2
```

Any insight into what this error signifies?

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.deterministic import CalendarFourier, DeterministicProcess
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_path = ' China population.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0)  

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
print(data.columns)

fourier = CalendarFourier(freq='A', order=10)  # Componentes de Fourier anuales

dp = DeterministicProcess(
    index=data.index,
    constant=True,
    order=1,
    seasonal=True,
    additional_terms=[fourier],
    drop=True,
)

model = LinearRegression()
X = dp.in_sample()  # Obtener las variables independientes
y = data['Population']  # Variable dependiente (población)

model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: From this url : https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.deterministic.DeterministicProcess.html
orderint, default 0
The order of the tim trend to include. For example, 2 will include both linear and quadratic terms. 0 exclude time trend terms.
You can edit `order=1` to `order=2`

Comment: I attempted to set order=0, order=1, order=2, but the same error persists

Comment: Show the part of the traceback with the location where the exception is raised. `seasonal=True` : what seasonality do you expect with annual data?

Comment: Thanks, Josef. The problem was with that parameter. It worked when seasonal=False. I didn't realize that with annual data, you wouldn't expect seasonality